# while validating timeStamp actual and expected is varying by one second that probably is execution time . how to handle it

Tags: java, rest-assured

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd’T’HH:mm:ss’Z’")
                                .format(Calendar.getInstant().getTime());
```

Expected : `"2023-07-11T16:51:41Z"`
Actual : `"2023-07-11T16:51:42Z"`

Here the only difference is in the seconds of actual time and expected time

Comment: Maybe because you are getting the "actual timestamp" in previous of later statement therefore you are getting this difference.

Comment: Basically, stop depending on "the current instant in time" as an untestable, always-changing thing. Change to use java.time, and pass in a Clock as a dependency.

Comment: If you want to allow offsets of one or two seconds, you can compute a `Duration` between actual and expected time and let it pass your test if the duration in seconds is 1 or less, for example.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing timestamps in tests, it's common for there to be a slight variation due to the execution time of the code. To handle this situation, you can introduce a tolerance or buffer when comparing timestamps. Here's an example of how you can handle it in Java:-

> import java.time.Instant;
> import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
>
> Instant expectedTimestamp = Instant.parse("2023-07-11T16:51:41Z");
> Instant actualTimestamp = Instant.parse("2023-07-11T16:51:42Z"); long
> toleranceSeconds = 1; // Define your tolerance in seconds
>
> boolean timestampsMatch =
> Math.abs(ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(expectedTimestamp,
> actualTimestamp)) <= toleranceSeconds;
>
> System.out.println("Timestamps match: " + timestampsMatch);

In the above example, a tolerance of 1 second is defined **(toleranceSeconds = 1)**. The Math.abs() function is used to calculate the absolute difference in seconds between the expected and actual timestamps. If the absolute difference is less than or equal to the defined tolerance, then the timestamps are considered to match.

You can adjust the value of toleranceSeconds according to your specific needs and requirements. Keep in mind that a larger tolerance may result in a higher chance of false positives or incorrect matches.

***By introducing a tolerance, you account for slight variations in execution time and ensure that the test passes even if the timestamps differ by a small amount.***